# Matching Password Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a login screen where I need to display the password requirements and matching status. Currently, the password requirements are working as needed, but the problem I am having is with the matching password field addon that needs to go from a gray (null and default) to a red "X" (missing or mismatching password) or green "✔" (matching passwords), just as it happens with the password requirements status.

**Here's the working** [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UXEngineer/ax6egohs/29/)

Such status must be displayed using the following tag as it is part of Bootstrap's input-group:

```
<span id="matchpswstatus" class="input-group-addon">✖</span>
```

This is part of the bootstrap group, like so:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="password" id="matchpsw" name="matchpsw" class="form-control reenterpassword" placeholder="Re-enter Password" required />
    <span id="matchpswstatus" class="input-group-addon">✖</span>
</div>
```

I would appreciate any help in getting the gray "✖" to turn red in case a User re-enters a mismatching password OR to turn into a green "✔" in case both passwords are a match.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I added this when you check the value:

```
$("#matchpswstatus").html(password == $(this).val() ? "&#10004;" : "&#10006");

if (password == $(this).val() ){
    $("#matchpswstatus").css("color", "green");
} else {
    $("#matchpswstatus").css("color", "red");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hxz9oapc/